# Record count in Access report does export to Excel

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access 2010 report that has lines for record count in the group footer. However when I export to Excel the Record counts are missing. Any clues?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the "record count" is part of the Access interface, and not part of the actual data.

If you need a count of the records, you will have to export that seperately, or simply add a cell to Excel that does the count for you.

Comment: Sounds reasonably, but the idea to "...export that separately..." makes a little uneasy. I just want to export everything once. Adding a count cell to Excel seems like the easiest solution. I'll see if I get any other responses. Thanks.

Comment: Well, add the count to the query you're using to export it then.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying. If the count is part of the original query, it should carry over to Excel after the export. For me it's a matter figuring out the logic. The original query just returns a list of sorted records and let's Access do the grouping and counting. Your suggestion sounds like I now need to do the grouping and counting in the query and somehow store the count (for each group) to be used in Access. If I have time, I'll give this shot, but if there any examples on the web please refer me. Thanks for your help.